# Looking to write a generic method in selenium to search for an webelement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a generic method to search for an element by locator but want a method (Selenium C#) which looks for an element to get displayed on UI. It should iterate through 4 seconds and for a given period before timing out.

Comment: Method which I wrote is below :

Comment: public static IWebElement WaitForElement(By selector)
            WebDriverWait wait = new 
 WebDriverWait(WebDriverProperty.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            return wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return d.FindElement(selector);
                    
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }

Comment: public static IWebElement WaitForElement(By selector)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverProperty.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            return wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return d.FindElement(selector);
                    
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }